# problems cxf with websphere

Tags: websphere, cxf, webservices-client

I want to call a web service by JaxWsProxyFactoryBean. I tested in tomcat 6 and everything was OK, but when I deployed on WAS 7 it didn`t work.

My problem is:
when I call factory.create() method of this code:

```
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        factory.setServiceClass(CustomerServices.class);
        factory.setAddress("http://host:port/MyServices");
        factory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
        factory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
        CustomerServices client = (CustomerServices) factory.create();
```

I got this exception: ServiceConstructionException 
which tells me 'e.getMessage()   = null'

Is there any uncompatibility between my pom below with WAS 7?

--pom.xml--

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--log-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--commons-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Spring-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring AOP + AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AOP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- db connection and  pooling -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc-license-cisuz</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache CXF dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-aegis</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>quartz</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--date & time-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.persianCalender</groupId>
        <artifactId>simpleCalender</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>wstx-asl</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-resolver</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
        <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <cxf.version>2.2.9</cxf.version>
    </properties>

Answer (score 0):

Do the instructions here on the Apache CXF web site for specific application servers help?

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html#ApplicationServerSpecificConfigurationGuide-ForWebSphere6.1.0.29%2CV7andV8

Can you please try those out?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found another solution instead of using JaxWsProxyFactoryBean as a client.
we should use another client;

```
public final static QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("URL", "MyServiceImplService");


        MyServiceImplService ss = new MyServiceImplService (wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
        CustomerServices port = ss.getMyServiceImplPort();
        port.myMethod(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had more or less the same problems deploying JAX-WS Web Services on WebSphere 7 using CXF for the WS and Maven for the build.

You can find many informations on the web; I tried to collect them all toghether and posted a blog post at http://bit.ly/1wCyjfx.

Here you can find dependencies and WAR packaging sections that is working right now for me (in my app, I publish some service and consume some other service)  toghether with specific references to WAS 7 configurations.

Comment: Could it be that the blog post is no longer available?

Comment: The previously provided link is no longer available. I've updated the link. Thanks.